# How can I get both the content and the head from a Wordpress REST API GET or HEAD request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, wordpress

I am trying to make an app for my custom wordpress site. I recently installed the [JSON REST API (WP API)](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) plugin to my site and have been going through the documentation. I have tried using an NSMutableURLRequest to get the data through a GET request, and have been successful at getting just the content. However, nothing comes through when I do a HEAD request, even though `curl -I http://example.com/wp-json/posts` returns the proper HTTP head.

> me$ curl -I example.com/wp-json/posts HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 19:01:02 GMT 
>   Server: Apache 
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28 
>   X-Pingback: http://example.com/xmlrpc.php
>   X-WP-Total: 288
>   X-WP-TotalPages: 29 
>   Last-Modified: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 15:21:37 GMT 
>   Vary: User-Agent
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/wp-json/posts"]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"HEAD"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;


NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
NSLog(@"Data: %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Is there a proper way to get the HTTP head from a REST API call, or better yet get the response from the GET request and the HEAD request together? I am going to put the data into a database so I can call it later, and I really need the posts and the head. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't a HEAD request just the same as a GET request, but HEAD doesn't return the content?  I.e. you'll get the same headers, but no content, with HEAD?

Comment: Yes, this is true. However, when I tried to do a HEAD request, it returned nothing. I am trying to get both the content and the head from the same call.

Comment: Right-- so, don't use the HEAD at all as it is just a subset of GET?

Comment: Yes, that would be amazing, but I do not know how to do that and cannot find how to do that. That is my question.